# Rest API devolvendo Token

Tags: api, swift, rest, post, get

Preciso desenvolver uma aplicação em *Swift* estou tentando consumindo uma *API* para realizar login e quando logar a aplicação terá que mandar um *Token*, mas esse *Token* já é existente na *API*, gostaria de saber como eu mando ele? É uma espécie de `Request` `Response`?

Comment: Com as informações que você está disponibilizando não tem com alguém te ajudar. É preciso que você ou poste o link da api ou o resultado json (data) que você recebe como resposta do servidor. Para você converter a resposta (data) JSON para string use `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")`

Comment: Já consegui resolver o problema, obrigado.